# Magento2 - Run composer require without cli

Tags: composer, cli

I don't have access to ssh on my `cpanel`.

How is it possible to run composer require(`composer require razorpay/magento`) without any cli interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but it is difficult

Essentially you will need a php wrapper

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244866/10121426

Another option is to composer locally on your machine and upload composer.json, composer.lock and vendor folder.

Try to match php versions

Answer (score 0):

You *will* need CLI sooner or later so I suggest you sort that out with yor hosting provider ass soon as you can. As far as I know you cannot install modules using composer without CLI. Either way you will need to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and some other commands to get your new module working anyway.

Comment: i can add cli commmands and run using custom php files like
<?php

print_r(system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade'));

but i can't run composer